# one dimension tuple to two dimension numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Convert a tuple into a Numpy matrix with the below conditions:

- The shape of the array should be `len(tuple)` x `len(tuple)`, ie a square matrix.
- Elements in array at the location specified by `(index of the element in the tuple, the value of the element in the tuple)` should be one.

For example, I have a random tuple, like below:

```
# index means row ,value means col
(2,0,1)
```

I use two loop to change this tuple into Numpy array:

```
def get_np_represent(result):
    two_D = []
    for row in range(len(result)):
        one_D = []
        for col in range(len(result)):
            if result[row] == col:
                one_D.append(1)
            else:
                one_D.append(0)
        two_D.append(one_D)
    return np.array(two_D)
```

output:

```
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

But I have 10,000,000 such tuple, Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this? Manipulate the matrix is quite faster than for loop.

```
import numpy as np

t = (2, 0, 1)
x = np.zeros([len(t),len(t)])

for i,v in enumerate(t):
    x[i, v] = 1

print(x)
```

outputs:

```
[[0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0.]]
```

Comment: more Intuitive, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

For example (setting up from Ke)

```
t = (2, 0, 1)
x = np.zeros([len(t),len(t)])
x[np.arange(len(x)),t]=1
x
Out[145]: 
array([[0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.]])
```

Comment: I like this one, more concise.